# How to calculate real number

Tags: c#

I am trying to add some real numbers retrieved from data grid view.
But have problem in decimal part of number.
It shows 5.2 + 5.8 equal to 9.992128378393 some thing like this 
How can i fix this
This is what i am trying

```
Double i=0;
i = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(Datagridview.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(Datagridview.Rows[x+1].Cells[0].Value))
```

Comment: Just round the number to your desired amount of decimal places with `Math.Round`

Comment: No need to convert  Whole expression to double. result of double + double is double

Comment: What is best variable for sum  decimal?

Comment: @user2588132 probably the best variable to sum decimal is `d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
 Double i=0;
i = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(Datagridview.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(Datagridview.Rows[x+1].Cells[0].Value))
i=Math.Round(i);
```

See this Ideone https://ideone.com/pPfUJY

Comment: Thanks you this work but with little change i=Math.Round(i,1)